# Usar doble variable en un ciclo for en Go lang

Tags: bucle-for, bucles, go

tengo un problema al tratar de ejecutar un código en lenguaje Go, resulta que tengo que imprimir un cuadrado latino de "n" numeros, el cual  cada una de sus N-1 filas contiene la rotación de la fila anterior un lugar a la derecha.
ejemplo:

cuadrado latino de orden 4:
1 2 3 4

2 3 4 1

3 4 1 2

4 1 2 3

Pero cuando trato de ejecutar el código no me es permitido poner dos variables ni asignarle a la variable en este casi K=1,  en los ciclos For que se usa para poder darle ese acomodo a las variables, específicamente en el tercer For, esto debido a que primero programé el algoritmo en c++, ya que en Go soy principiante, y en c++ si me es permitido hacer estos movimientos,  les paso mi código

Si me pueden apoyar se los agradezco mucho.

```
package main
import "fmt"
func main(){
    
var n,i,j,k int

fmt.Println("Ingresa tamaño del cuadrado")
fmt.Scanf("%d", &n)

for i=1;i<=n;i++ { 
        
  for j=i,k=1; k <=n ;  k++, j++ {
            
    if j>n {
                
     for j=1; k <= n ; k++ , j++ {
        fmt.Println(" %d",j)
     }               
      }else{
        fmt.Printl(" %d",j)
        }
    }
  }                 
}
```

Comment: no olvide marcar la respuesta como aceptada porfavor y si puedes darle un upvote te lo agradecería tambien ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí he preparado un ejemplo de como solucionar tu problema implmentado en go.

He creado un array de 2 dimensiones que simula tu matrix. Luego he empleado dos bucles para recorrer la matriz.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    n := 4

    rows := make([][]int, n)

    for j := 0; j < n; j++ {
        rows[j] = make([]int, n)
        for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
            if j <= 0 {
                rows[j][i] = i + 1
                continue
            }

            if i+1 < n {
                rows[j][i] = rows[j-1][i+1]
                continue
            }

            rows[j][i] = rows[j-1][n-i-1]
        }
    }

    fmt.Printf("%+v \n", rows)
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/9RyXGbOwXbx

Comment: Muchas gracias !! me ha servido bastante

Comment: no olvide marcar la respuesta como aceptada porfavor y si puedes darle un upvote te lo agradecería tambien ;)